# Which problem is Oppenheimer working on in this picture?

Tags: soft-question, quantum-electrodynamics, history, dirac-equation

Does anybody recognize the equations on the blackboard?

Above his hand, with the $\gamma_k$ term and its complex conjugate, it looks like a written out matrix representation of a Hamiltonian $U$, further below there's the constant $z = 13.7$, so perhaps something related to the binding energy of the nucleus, and it looks like he's working on an expansion of the polynomial (I couldn't make out the exponent):
$$
q g^2 (1 + \alpha z)^{...}
$$
(of which is it a representation?)

[image: Oppenheimer writing on the blackboard]

Comment: How to put together an Ikea couch

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not asking about a concept in physics

Comment: There's a lot of work that is either covered or too small (or otherwise illegible) to make out what he's writing, so don't be surprised if this gets no answer.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of not-very-distinctive stuff here, that's a really hard question. A random blackboard can usually give some indication of what was being worked on but this is pretty hard to read.